# problem with hebrew - MySql, c#

Tags: c#, mysql, hebrew

i've problem to insert hebrew strings to MySql.

**Introduction**

1. I set the MySql to Utf8.
2. I set the table as charset utf8 with collation uft8_general_ci
3. I set the connection string as it: "Server=*;Database=*;Uid=*;Pwd=*; charset=utf8;"
4. I write stored procedure for using it by c#.
5. Version of MySql: 5.1.53

when i simply insert hebrew string to table by MySql
as it :

```
insert into temp_table (temp_column) values ('ערך')
```

i saw as proper.
if i set stored procedure as it..i see gibberish.

when i call it by c# i get exception as 'Incorrect string value: '\xD7\xAA\xD7\xA8...' for column...'

if i insert english strings, so i get all as proper.

any idea?

Comment: Can you post the C# code you use for inserting a value? And show the column definition as well, please.

Comment: Can you show both your stored proc and the code you use to call it from C#

Comment: CREATE TABLE `city` ( `CityID` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `CityName` varchar(100) NOT NULL, `CitySynonyms` mediumtext, `CityNumberPostOffice` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, `UpdatedDate` date DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`CityID`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`SPInsertUpdateCity`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SPInsertUpdateCity`(
in SP_CityName VARCHAR(100),
in SP_CitySynonyms mediumtext,
in SP_CityNumberPostOffice varchar(100),
in SP_CityUpdatedDate date)
BEGIN
   if(not exists(select CityID from city where CityName = SP_CityName)) then
 insert into city(CityName, CitySynonyms, CityNumberPostOffice ,UpdatedDate)
 values(SP_CityName, CONCAT(',',SP_CitySynonyms, ','),SP_CityNumberPostOffice,SP_CityUpdatedDate);

Comment: else 
      if((exists(select cityId from city where CityName = SP_CityName and (UpdatedDate < SP_CityUpdatedDate or UpdatedDate = SP_CityUpdatedDate))) and
   not exists(SELECT CitySynonyms FROM city WHERE CitySynonyms in(select CitySynonyms from city where CitySynonyms like CONCAT('%,',SP_CitySynonyms,',%')))) then
         update city
         set
  CitySynonyms = CONCAT(CitySynonyms,SP_CitySynonyms,','),UpdatedDate = SP_CityUpdatedDate;
      end if;
   end if;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

Comment: MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();                
                    conn.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
                    MySqlCommand cmd = GetMySqlCommand(new string[] { "SP_CityName", "SP_CitySynonyms", "SP_CityNumberPostOffice", "SP_CityUpdatedDate" }, xml);
                    cmd.CommandText = "SPInsertUpdateCity";
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: the code of GetMySqlCommand: MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(); for (int i = 0; i < attributes.Length; i++) { XmlNode node = xml.SelectSingleNode("//" + attributes[i]); if (node != null) { string value = node.InnerText; cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + attributes[i], value); cmd.Parameters["@" + attributes[i]].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; } } return cmd;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i added to stored procedure charset utf8

in SP_CityName VARCHAR(100) charset utf8,
in SP_CitySynonyms mediumtext charset utf8

and now it works fine... thanks a lot to u all.

Answer (score 2):

You said you set the table as charset UTF8, but did you set the column encoding to UTF8 too ?

And/or try [sending a `SET NAMES utf8;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) command to MySql before executing your stored procedure.

> SET NAMES indicates what character set
>   the client will use to send SQL
>   statements to the server. Thus, SET
>   NAMES 'cp1251' tells the server,
>   “future incoming messages from this
>   client are in character set cp1251.”
>   It also specifies the character set
>   that the server should use for sending
>   results back to the client. (For
>   example, it indicates what character
>   set to use for column values if you
>   use a SELECT statement.)

Comment: i set the columns as utf8 too.. it's not help:(. i try also to send set names utf8; my mysql commander.. it's says query ok 0 rows affected... show: 
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
| Variable_name            | Value
    | character_set_client     | utf8
    | character_set_connection | utf8
  | character_set_database   | utf8
  | character_set_filesystem | binary
 | character_set_results    | utf8
 | character_set_server     | utf8
| character_set_system     | utf8
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: 'set names' only affects that specific connection, it's not a general mysql setting. Have you tried sending 'set names' immediately before your stored procedure, while on the same connection ?

Comment: Also, try using a Mysql admin program like sqlyog or phpmyadmin to insert some test data. That should help to see whether the problem is in your C# connection code or the database structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use Text/LongText instead of varchar. Also use Collation as utf8_general_ci