# Why PHP script doesn't show Unicode text in WAMP/MySQL Server

Tags: php, sql, unicode

When I installed a new WAMP server(2.1), I can only see ????? characters instead of some Unicode text. In phpMyAdmin I can see text correctly in database (UTF8).

It worked in an earlier WAMP version 2.0.

However, my browser shows Unicode text correctly from other sites.

Comment: It's an encoding problem. I had similar problem when you retrieve code from Db try with "mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");"right after you connect and before you move any data.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287821/mysql-db-question-marks-instead-of-hebrew-characters)

Comment: Is this true only for values that come out of the DB or even constns in you PHP files? Or only PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: @luca Thank you very much for your help, that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have a configuration error in at least one of the following areas:

- mysql-database - you may have corrupted chars in the database (most common case)
- mysql - check http://i18n.ro/Configurare_MySQL_pentru_UTF-8
- php - check http://i18n.ro/Configurare_PHP_pentru_UTF-8
- apache - http://i18n.ro/Configurare_Apache_pentru_UTF-8