# Getting Gibberish on phpmyadmin output

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to send Hebrew content through to show up on phpmyadmin. English letters go through perfectly, but Hebrew gives me something like this: ×—×Ÿ ×“×•××§.

phpmyadmin collation is set on utf8_unicode_ci (Also tried utf8_general_ci). How can I solve it?

This is my code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$servername = "//";
$username = "//";
$password = "//";
$dbname = "//";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "INSERT INTO nigunim (name, time, day)
VALUES ('בדיקה', 'בדיקה', 'בדיקה')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: what is the actual database encoding? and table, and columns!

Comment: @delboy1978uk Thanks. utf8_general_ci, also the columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836731/how-to-insert-an-hebrew-value-into-a-mysql-db-in-php

Comment: ok, and what is the charset HTML meta tag for your web GUI phpmyadmin? Incidentally, you are FAR better using HeidiSQL (Win) or Sequel Pro (Mac).

Comment: @MathieuDormeval I saw and tried that solution, but it did not work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert an hebrew value into a mysql db in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836731/how-to-insert-an-hebrew-value-into-a-mysql-db-in-php)

Comment: once you have checked the charset of phpmyadmin, you should install one of those applications and check without going through a web server, which is what phpmyadmin is doing

Comment: also, check the actual connection initiated is utf 8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: @delboy1978uk Thanks, I checked that under  information_schema > schemata and it is set on utf8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed by **creating a new table** and then adding `mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conn);` along with making sure collation is set to  utf8_general_ci.