# Mysql collation for hebrew

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add few hebrew values to mySql db. I tried few collation options to column names and shema, but I still receiving the same result, as in the picture. Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Update: This answer [How to insert an hebrew value into a mysql db in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836731/how-to-insert-an-hebrew-value-into-a-mysql-db-in-php) and this command
String changeCollation = "ALTER TABLE Products CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci"; doesn't helps.