# data retrieved from database in Hebrew presented as question mark

Tags: php, mysqli

I did all changes as the answer instructed  in 
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287821/mysql-db-question-marks-instead-of-hebrew-characters)
in order to be able to print hebrew strings coming from the database but didnt work.

this is my php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dbName";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. " - Score: " . $row["score"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

every thing works accept that insted of the hebrew strings i only see question marks (???).
any idea why??

Answer (score -1):

Set the Browser's Character Settings to Hebrew.

FireFox:Tools=>Options=>Content=>Advanced=>Fallback Character Encoding = Hebrew

Google Chrome: Menu=>Settings=>Show Advanced Settings=>Language and input settings

**UPDATE:**
When you save the text first recode the text.

Try using GNU Recode?

```
$text = mysqli_real_escape_string(recode_string(characterSet,$text));
```

Where *characterSet* complies with RFC-1345, e.g. 'latin1'
Valid Character sets: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1345.html