# Laravel 5 - PHP storm - seeder Hebrew

Tags: php, laravel, hebrew

I am trying to seed my DB categories Table with Hebrew content.
I can seed my Table with English.
can someone please tell me how can I do that?

OK so it is still not working..
I tried using 'utf8_general_ci' and also the "N'אופנה".

There are my files:

**database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ]
```

**DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
DB::table('categories')->insert(array(
                array('id' => NULL, 'category_name' => "N'אופנה", 'created_at' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"), 'updated_at' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s") ),
                array('id' => NULL, 'category_name' => 'aaa', 'created_at' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"), 'updated_at' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s") ),
        ));
```

**database structure**

[image: database structure]

**categories structure**

[image]

**categories table**

[image]

**my project encoding**

[image: my project encoding]

Comment: Are you using `forge`? If not. Can you tell me the name of your database?

Comment: My DB name is 'ibay'

Comment: Use Hebrew characters?

Comment: Yes, do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Have you checked your editor character set?

Comment: Yes, it is encoded to UTF-8, you can see below I have posted the current status with pictures

Comment: Please follow the instructions in answer with 9 votes **[HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287821/mysql-db-question-marks-instead-of-hebrew-characters)**, you have to be able to store Hebrew characters  manualy first, and then try to store them by seeds.

Comment: manually works either way.. but it's like laravel framework shuts it down somehow

Comment: The person in the link is not using laravel framework

Comment: I alreadey set my DB to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES I solved the problem !! ok so how to fix that? there you go:

Inside PHP Storm ->

changing the font in "Settings | Appearance | Override default fonts"

looks like the font used by the GUI Theme is not fully unicode

there is the link that I found my answer :)

[Hebrew when creating files/projects](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5489136;jsessionid=A5580CA810CDE81EA55853E937E8A201)

Thank you everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using forge then try this maybe this will work.

Try changing your database to this:

```
   'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'ibay'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ]
```

Or you could try this if the first didn't work:

```
     'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'ibay',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ]
```

In databaseSeeder.php

```
 return DB::table('categories')->insert(array(
            array('id' => NULL, 'category_name' => 'אופנה', 'created_at' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"), 'updated_at' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s") ),
            array('id' => NULL, 'category_name' => 'aaa', 'created_at' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"), 'updated_at' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s") )
    ));
```

In your database schema:

Change your database `collation` to `utf8 collate utf8_general_ci`

If the above is not also working try to change your queries to:

```
 return DB::table('categories')->insert(array(
            array('id' => NULL, 'category_name' => "N'אופנה", 'created_at' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"), 'updated_at' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s") ),
            array('id' => NULL, 'category_name' => 'aaa', 'created_at' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"), 'updated_at' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s") )
    ));
```

> N stands for National language character set. Which means that you are passing an NCHAR, NVARCHAR or NTEXT value

Comment: It is still not working.. the 'category_name' stay empty when I'm using Hebrew.

Comment: I am using .env file, but still tried the second option.. its still fill it with empty string :\

Comment: Its wired becuse I'm able to fill English and all config are for utf-8

Comment: So the 1st array can't insert in your database?