# SQL query in android doesn't recognize hebrew letters despite in wamp server it does

Tags: java, android, mysql, wampserver

When i'm trying to find record by hebrew field it doesn't return any data when executing my query. Despite the fact that when i am pasting the same query in my wampserver the query return the rights answer!

I define the table and the fields as `utf8_general_ci` and still the problem occurred. please help.

```
public ArrayList<String> findPartnersFast(String semester , String course , String city) {
        String currentQuery = "SELECT * FROM fast_reg " + "WHERE course = " + "'" + "מבוא למקרוכלכלה"  +  "'" ;
        ArrayList<String> arrayOfResults = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            res = statement.executeQuery(currentQuery);
            Log.d("DBmanipulation" , currentQuery);
            while(res.next()) {
                Log.d("DBmanipulation" , "in while loop!");
                String temp = res.getString("student_name");
                arrayOfResults.add(temp);
                Log.d("DBmanipulation", "name: " + temp);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (res != null) {
                    res.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        return arrayOfResults;
    }
```

LOG:

```
03-20 20:29:09.400 3593-4082/com.example.uvalerx073037.finalproject_correct D/Register: In BackGround 
03-20 20:29:09.400 3593-4082/com.example.uvalerx073037.finalproject_correct I/System.out: conneting to Database... 
03-20 20:29:09.532 3593-4082/com.example.uvalerx073037.finalproject_correct I/System.out: Connection Successful 
03-20 20:29:09.550 3593-4082/com.example.uvalerx073037.finalproject_correct D/DBmanipulation: SELECT * FROM fast_reg WHERE course = 'מבוא למקרוכלכלה' 
03-20 20:29:09.557 3593-4082/com.example.uvalerx073037.finalproject_correct I/System.out: connection close properly
```

Comment: That is a good question! it took me days figure it out ;);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that sql table row and field encoded correctly:

1. the db collation has to be utf8_general_ci.
2. the collation of the table with hebrew has to be utf8_general_ci
3. In your connection to the database you need to use setting that will clear the   charset, I know that in php the connection setting needs to be like that:
   ('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
4. in your xhtml tag, in android, you need to define that this page uses utf8:
5. after selecting the db in the connection script you need to put mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

take a look at this answer also:
[MySQL db question marks instead of hebrew characters..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287821/mysql-db-question-marks-instead-of-hebrew-characters)

Comment: In addition to your answer with JDBC connection like in step number 3 in your explanation i did: con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8","user","passwd");