# Database and tables' collation is set to utf8-general-ci, still getting cyrillic characters replaced by '?'

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am trying to get and display data from MySQL, and everything is working fine, except that cyrillic characters get replaced by question marks '?'. I have implemented all recomendations from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296171). I have my MySQL database and it's tables' collation set to 'utf8-general-ci'. I have the `<meta charset=utf-8>` tag in my html file. Still get this problem.

Comment: Is your PHP file saved in UTF-8 encoding? Check your editor. Most provide this in "save as", "options", "settings" or other menu. I would also wrap "utf-8" in quotes in the meta tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831 gives a more specific answer -- namely why you get question marks.